# facebook ios sdk 4.16 custom login button didn't fire safari web view at the 1st click

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I've implemented a custom Facebook login button in my app. The problem is when click the login button at the very first time (cache token expired or cleared), the safari web view authorize page will not be fired until I re-request like

`[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:permission:fromViewController:handler]`

again. Does anyone know what is the potential problem?
I try to catch the 1st login request exception error and have tried every loginBehavior but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by upgrade Facebook SDK to 4.17. It's Facebook SDK bug.